# Openstack Cloud

Tags: cloud, openstack

I have 30 servers of misc types, with different CPU, RAM, HDD etc.

Thinking of using Openstack to make all the servers into a big cloud --- and then use Openstack to make several (say 20 VM's) Virtual machine instances on the "big cloud" created from the 30 servers.

Ie. if I have total 128 GB of Ram spread on those 30 servers, would it be possible to use Openstack Compute to control the resources and then run those virtual machines created across the entire "big cloud".

Comment: Each VM lives on one underlying server, so a 30 node cluster with only 20 VMs really doesn't make sense - at least 10 of the servers would be entirely unused.

Comment: OK --- let me rephrase.... then say I want to create 50 VM's..... My whole objective is not to put one VM per server.

Comment: My objective is to "combine the resources" on all the nodes and then have VM's run on this cloud.... and being able to add nodes to the cloud if VM's use up too much CPU, RAM or whatever.....

Comment: A VM cannot run on more than one server (i.e. two servers with 2 GB of RAM won't let you combine them into one single 4 GB VM).

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, the answer is no: you cannot pool resources across multiple host servers into a single VM. A VM has only one host, though any given host can have multiple VMs.

If you're trying to just pool the resources so that you can adjust and tweak the usage of multiple VMs per host, then yes, you're thinking correctly.

### Example 1 (good):

You have 20 hosts with 16GB of RAM each. You want to make 40 VMs of various sizes, totalling around 256GB of RAM but none exceeding 16GB. This works, and leaves enough room for host failures, overhead, and expansion.

### Example 2 (bad):

You have 20 hosts with 2GB of RAM each. You want to make 10 VMs with 4GB of RAM each. This does **not** work, since VMs can't exceed the capabilities of a single host. Also, you left no room for host failures or overhead.

### Example 3 (inefficient):

You have 20 hosts with 8GB of RAM each. You want to make 20 VMs with 8GB of RAM each, minus host overhead. Go ahead and have a blast... but why?

---

To further clarify, the above examples work the same for the number of CPU cores you assign to guests. You can't give a guests more virtual CPUs or cores than a single host has.

Comment: Hi Hyppy. Thanks for your answer..... but I am afraid maybe you misunderstand :) If I have 30 servers (each has ~4 GB) and the total RAM is 128 GB and say 60 cores. Storage is irrelevant in this case. Then would I be able to create say 3 VM each having 20 cores and 40 GB of RAM each..... is that possible using Openstack? or need KVM or something else? Clustering?

Comment: @Chris No, that's not possible with OpenStack, and it's not really possible at all.

Comment: @Chris I added some examples to further clarify the point I was trying to make.

Comment: Thanks for your advice --- but then how do you combine the resources so you can do Computing? (Nova Compute)...... Hypervisors added to the architecture?  How does Amazon do it? I am sure they do not have just one HUGE gigantic computer.. or unlimited machines for all those instances people are making..... essentially I just want to group all the resources together and then make virtual machines out of it . Of course I know if I only have say 128 GB of RAM in the cloud, there would be no way to have more than this available unless I "cheat" and "oversubscribe" it. Kindly thx in adv for ur help

Comment: Single System Image computing is only a good idea when your application is coded to understand the difference between local and remote RAM and CPU. Unless you're doing serious science, your applications are unlikely to be coded as such.

Comment: @Chris They certainly do have datacenters full of tens of thousands of physical servers. No single instance is larger than a single host server, period.  If you want to combine the power of multiple servers, then you can look into various grid/clustering technologies, but loads must be specifically designed to work in those environments. You definitely are not going to run an instance of Windows or Ubuntu that thinks it has 20 servers' worth of CPUs available to it.

Comment: @Hyppy, I am trying to create cloud host using all these servers..... what clustering or grid technology would you recommend?
Also, you mention no single instance is larger than a single host server --- fair enough, but what happens if that server crashes? Overstack can throw the VM to another server on the fly? or... downtime?

Comment: A VM cloud and grid/cluster computing are two completely separate things, and generally can't be combined.

Comment: but isnt making a cloud because you do not want any single server to crash and affect everything? basically i am looking to avoid having a ton of idle resources while being able to have Virtual machines running on the "cloud".....

Comment: "but isnt making a cloud because you do not want any single server to crash and affect everything?" Amazon's documentation **explicitly** warns you that your servers could crash and go away at any time. The key to reliability is load balancing and fault tolerance, not invulnerable servers.